# The side panel (attributes) doesn't show up properly (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

It appears again after I enter something in the search bar and delete it. Only after I search for something and delete the search query, the complete attributes/properties panel is visible again. Here is the [video link](https://vimeo.com/324926080) for more details.

**Update (more information)**:

This is the attributes panel I am talking about:

[The attributes panel appearing as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRLi6.png)

Now, sometimes I have to search for some more attributes, like for textSize attribute for a `TextView`. So, I go the `View all attributes` page (in the same panel by clicking the [double-pointed arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fR5R.png). This is the state of the panel now:

[All attributes panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkOZ.png)

On returning back to the original state of the panel (`View fewer attributes`) by again clicking the double pointer arrows, this is the state of the panel:

[Original panel with many options missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6do7.png) (compare it with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRLi6.png))

My computer details:

```
Memory: 7.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
GNOME: 3.28.2
OS Type: 64-bit
Disk: 200.6 GB
```

Android Studio information:

```
Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 16, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please tell us: What do you expect to happen with the *search bar* after you deleted your entered query-text ? Whz does the side-panel (attributes) don't show up properly? For each question you can  post 2 images: (a) what _happend_ (b) what you _expected_.

Comment: @hc_dev I have updated the question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue.

Here is a fix that "cleaned up" the Attribute pane behavior for me: In the Attributes pane, click the More Options icon (cog in the upper right) and select **All attributes table**. That "restored" things. The other option there is **XML attribute editor**. I don't know how my IDE got switched to **XML**, but once I changed it back to **All** everything is fine now.